# My data binding works but my input ng-model isn't updating when I $update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I do this {{newStore1}} and $scope.newStore1 = 'Owl Store';, when the page loads, the text says Owl Store. That data binding's all good. If I make an input box and give it the model newStoreName, that works too, for the most part...

```
{{newStore1}}
<form data-ng-submit="storeUpdate()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newStore1">
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The new store name shows as null. Even though *as I type* in the text box, the {{newStore}} updates with the text. but when I do this, it gives me a null value.

```
    $scope.storeUpdate = function(){


        Users.get({email:$scope.global.user.email}, function(user3) {
            user3[0].store.push($scope.newStore1); // $scope.newStore1 is working in html but is 'null' here
            user3[0].$update(function(response) {
                Users.query({}, function(users) {
                    $scope.users = users;
                    $scope.global.user = response;
                });
            });
        });   
    };
```

Comment: always have a dot in `ng-model` so you can be sure to take advantage of object inheritance when scopes start getting nested. Primitives won't 2 way bind in nested scopes

Comment: so data-ng-model="store.name"?

Comment: If I put a dot in the ng-model name, when I hit submit, it says "Cannot read property "name" of undefined."

Comment: you should initialize your `store` in your controller `var store = {};` @charlietfl why don't you put your comment as an answer?

Comment: I'll try to remember to up-vote you guys when I get 15 reputation points. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

in your controller define:

`$scope.store = {};`

or if you do not want to declare it in your controller, in your HTML you need to declare the model at high level like:

```
<div ng-model="store.name">
  {{store.name}}
  <form data-ng-submit="storeUpdate()">
          <input type="text" ng-model="store.name">
          <input type="submit" />
  </form>
<div>
```